# PHPUnit: getMock('NonExistentClass') doesn't throw an error

Tags: mocking, phpunit

I'm not getting anywhere using mocks. I thought initially it was something to do with namespaces of my classes, but a sanity check revealed that it doesn't matter what I ask PHPUnit to mock, it proceeds without throwing up any errors at all:

```
class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    function testBla(){

        $this->getMockBuilder("IDontExist")->getMock(); // No error
        $this->getMock("IDontExist"); // No error

    }

}
```

The above would result in a passing test:

> OK (1 test, 0 assertions)
>
> Done.

Is this the expected behaviour? If so, how can I test if it's finding the class?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the expected behavior.